# Nix install unstable packages using ~/.nixpkgs/config.nix

Tags: nix

How can you install packages from the unstable channel using `nix-env -i all` via `~/.nixpkgs/config.nix`?

Answer (score 4):

Add following section at the beginning of your `~/.nixpkgs/config.nix`:

```
let unstable = import <nixpkgs> {}; in
```

Where `nixpkgs` is the name of the channel for unstable (check its name via nix-channel --list).

And prefix the packages you wish to install via unstable with `unstable.`.

Example - also gives access to unstable for usage with `nix-env -i`:

```
let
  config = {
    allowUnfree = true;

    packageOverrides = pkgs: with pkgs; 
      let jdk = openjdk11; in rec {
      unstable = import <nixpkgs-unstable> { inherit config; };

      all = pkgs.buildEnv {
        name = "all";

        paths = [
          htop
          nox
          nix-info
          nix-index
          haskell.compiler.ghc864
          haskellPackages.cabal-install
          unstable.haskellPackages.stack
          haskellPackages.hoogle
          haskellPackages.ghcid
          unstable.haskellPackages.cabal2nix
        ];
      };
    };
  };
in config
```

Or you could also do:

```
let unstable = import <nixpkgs> {}; in
{
  allowUnfree = true;

  packageOverrides = pkgs_: with pkgs_;
    let jdk = openjdk11; in {

    all = with pkgs; buildEnv {
      name = "all";

      paths = [
        htop
        nox
        nix-info
        nix-index
        haskell.compiler.ghc864
        haskellPackages.cabal-install
        unstable.haskellPackages.stack # this comes from the unstable channel
        haskellPackages.hoogle
        haskellPackages.ghcid
        unstable.haskellPackages.cabal2nix
      ];
    };
  };
}
```